# C++ equality in std::tr1::unordered_map

Tags: c++, equality, unordered-map

Is there a reason that std::tr1::unordered_map left out the equality (==) operator,
which exists for std::map ?

What is a good way to implement this? I am thinking of creating two sets of unordered_map::value_type, initializing them from the two hash_maps and then checking
for equality of the two sets.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` in C++0x does include equality/inequality overloads.

Answer (score 6):

It was a committee decision that imho was a mistake.  It has been corrected for std::unordered_map (in [C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3290.pdf)).

Using `std::equal` is not a good way to find the equality of unordered containers.  After all, they may not be in the same order.

[N3068](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3068.pdf) is the paper that introduced equality comparisons for the unordered containers.  It explains the motivation and the technique for determining equality.